# Check if a UIScrollView is Disposed in monotouch

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, idisposable

I want to call the `SetContentOffset` of a `UIScrollView` for example. Is there a way to check if the `ScrollView` object is disposed prior to calling it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If the view is disposed, you should not have a valid reference anymore. Can you show us what the specific scenario is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the thing to `null` wherever you `Dispose()` it. Then check for `null`.

This is a good pattern anyway, so the C# object can be GC'd.

Comment: I want to chech if it was disposed Implicitly not explicitly

Comment: Nothing is going to automatically dispose it unless your code does. Show a code example as @Krumelur suggested.